# Getting day of the week from timestamp using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

How do I get the day of the week from a timestamp in JavaScript?
I'd like to get this from a timestamp I specify, not the current date.

Thanks

Comment: please post whatever you have tried or have you?

Comment: http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp is a good place to start

Comment: Surprisingly, in this case the w3schools page is indeed a nice starting point. That doesn't mean one should refer to that web site in other situations.

Comment: How come not? I know it's not a complete source of knowledge, but my experience is, that it's a good place to start, before venturing out on the vast fields of Google...

Comment: I had remembered the site to contain lots of bad examples and mistakes. But during the last two days I didn't find any, so maybe they have improved a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var timestamp = 654524560; // UNIX timestamp in seconds
var xx = new Date();
xx.setTime(timestamp*1000); // javascript timestamps are in milliseconds
document.write(xx.toUTCString());
document.write(xx.getDay()); // the Day
```

---

#### 2020 Update

If this [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=toLocaleDateString) is acceptable for you you can use this one liner:

`new Date(<TIMESTAMP>).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' }); // e.g. Tuesday`

Comment: Wrong - gives the numeric day not the "day of the week".

Comment: shorter `(new Date(1557964800000)).getDay();`

Answer (score 27):

```
var timestamp = 1400000000;
var a = new Date(timestamp*1000);
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
var dayOfWeek = days[a.getDay()]
```

Now the "day of the week" is in the dayOfWeek variable.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to klidifia's answer, but for some reason the day of the week was off.  I had to update the 'days' array to start on Monday.

```
var timestamp = 1400000000;
var a = new Date(timestamp*1000);
var days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday'];
var dayOfWeek = days[a.getDay()]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try out the following:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var day = currentTime.getDate();
```

Comment: Wrong - gives the numeric day not the "day of the week"